# no right click on desktop

Tags: pcmanfm

I am running UBUNTU 12.04 and login in under a UBUNTU 3d. Recently I lost the ability to right click on the desktop. What happened was that after installing PCmanFM there was a an option that appeared on a menu along the lines of "add menus from other applications" (or something like that). As soon as I added that BOOM, my right click disappeared.

I have tried re-installing Gnome, Nautilus, PCmanfm, Advanced Settings, all with no luck. The only thing that restores the function of the right click is to remove PCmanFM. If I think about what started this, I tried to go into Configuration Editor/Gnome Terminal/Global there is a setting that says "Use menu Accelerators" not sure if this is related or not, but if I make a change to the value there it will not save.

The problem with all this is that I am trying to have Unity manage the desktop so that the Trash and Computer Icons are visible, however when I install PCmanFM and reboot, these trash & computer icons disappear. In any case I have two machines both with fresh installs, and the other machine has this setup fine, and on this machine I cant figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does right click work for a new user?

Comment: figured it out! there was an option in pcmanfm --desktop-pref that said "show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked. This menu can be accessed by a right click on the desktop, then to Desktop Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out! there was an option in pcmanfm --desktop-pref that said "show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked